# Travelling with Infant to Hong Kong - Need to use Kitchen

Tags: food-and-drink, hotels, children, hong-kong, restaurants

We are travelling Hong Kong next weekend. We have a 9 months old baby. She has lactose intolerance (*meaning she can't take any milk material*). We give her home made food, mainly, which is made of some rice and grains.

Now the thing is, none of the hotels do allow us to:

- Cook anything in hotel room with our pressure cooker and/or with our induction stove.
- Don't allow their restaurant' kitchen for this 5 minute cooking thing.
- Won't give us facility to just cook the food in their kitchen and give it back to us.

We are getting out of options. Any suggestions?

No, we cannot give "Baby Food" available in market, as we can't take risk with baby's health in other country.

Comment: http://holiday-rentals.co.uk

Comment: Sanyo Travel Cooker RN-38NF. A knockoff is  https://www.amazon.ca/Yazawa-Travel-multi-cooker-TVR21BK/dp/B006NT20YG on Amazon. Don't ask, don't tell anything to the hotel.

Comment: So how did you solve your problem finally? Did you stayed at the hotel you were planning earlier or took a service apartment instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Cook anything in hotel room with our pressure cooker and/or with our induction stove.

Standard at pretty much every hotel around the world. Fire hazard.

> Don't allow their restaurant' kitchen for this 5 minute cooking thing.

Standard at pretty much every restaurant around the world. Health, safety, fire etc. Are you familiar with a commercial gas stove? Probably not.

> Won't give us facility to just cook the food in their kitchen and give it back to us.

Most busy kitchens don't have the time, and most short-order cooks aren't interested in the liability of preparing unfamiliar (to them) meals for an infant with declared health issues.

Your two best choices are:

- Hotels with kitchenettes, also called apartment hotels, wherein you will find a standard domestic kitchen. Like AirB&B.
- Full-service hotels that are quite used to odd requests from guests. Some place that advertises 24-hour room service and 5-course formal dining. They will be happy to accommodate your dietary request because you will be paying a *fortune* for the room. Still highly unlikely they will cook your food though. They will cook your recipe, just not your ingredients.

One option you may not have considered is boil-in-bag meals. Something in a sealed bag that just needs 3 minutes in boiling water to prepare. This eliminates almost all of the objections the kitchen will have as they do not have to handle the food in any way. It needs to look commercial though - expect rejection (and food poisoning) if you prepare it yourself and use a Ziploc freezer bag.

Comment: What does last statement mean? "Rejection", "Ziploc"?

Comment: "Ziploc" is a US brand of what I (UK) was brought up to refer to as a *hermetically-resealable bag*, and which (according to Wikipedia) the US generically refers to as a [zipper storage bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_storage_bag).  The suggestion (as I understand it) is that if you procure commercial boil-in-the-bag meals suitable for your child, you may be able to persuade the hotel to heat them up for you; but that if you attempt to pre-prepare your own, in home-use zipper storage bags, the hotel is unlikely to volunteer to assist (and you may poison yourselves into the bargain).

Answer (score 23):

Rent an apartment hotel (serviced apartment) or an [Airbnb apartment](https://www.airbnb.com.au/s/Hong-Kong) instead. These always include kitchens and basic cooking utensils.

Also, in Hong Kong you can trust product labeling: if commercial baby food says "no dairy" on it, it won't contain any dairy.

Answer (score 4):

for cheaper alternatives try a youth hostel:

http://www.hostelworld.com/hostels/Hong-Kong/Hong-Kong

But be sure to verify that it is a licensed Guest House. You're supposed to prepare your own food in most of these hostels, so it should be exactly what you want.

Also, avoid Chungking Mansions at all costs which is reserved for adventurers.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how much preparation you need to do.

My advice is to use the local 7-Eleven or Circle K convenience stores. The vast majority of them will come equipped with a boiling water tap and a microwave. You will also find that you will never be more than a few paces from the nearest convenience store.

We don't like to walk in Hong Kong, because its really hot outside.